# Serialization of a Map

Tags: java, serialization

I have a a class that its like a wrapper for a map. It is a property list, mostly use for the sake of the name it looks like the following:

```
public class MyPropertyList implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID =  7896123434L;

    private LinkedHashMap<String,String> map;

    public static final String key1 = "key1";

    public static final String key2 = "key2";

    //More key values 

    public MyPropertyList(){
        map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

   }

    public void addProperty(String key, String value){
       map.put(key,value);
    }

    public LinkedHashMap<String,String> getMapping(){
        return map;
    }

    public int getSize(){
       return map.size;
    }

     //...Other delegated calls
}
```

It it a bad design? Does it present any issues? Is there a better design for that fulfills this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class from Java standar Library, which implements Serializable.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted offers no additional functionality over LinkedHashMap, so any code which uses this might just as well use LinkedHashMap directly.

Comment: I know, but in the code, they pretty much use it for the sake of Naming Conventions

Comment: @Sednus I don't understand who 'they' are, but what's wrong with the naming conventions of `Map`?